# How to get specific item listbox C# MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hi i try to get specific item from a listbox. I try to bind but i get crash. Using Prism framework how can i bind to get specific item from listbox, what template i need to make. This is test code:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectIndex}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="297" Margin="57,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="681">
                        <ListBoxItem>
                                <TextBlock Text="Test123"/>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>
                                <TextBlock Text="Test123"/>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
```

C# code:

```
public int SelectIndex
                {
                        get
                        {
                                return 1;
                        }
                }
```

How can i get if i want specific item from this list? What variable type need to make for binding listbox to select items?

Comment: If you are posting test code, please post the **whole** code.  Also, please post the exception you get when it crashes.  You haven't given any of us enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because you are binding `SelectedItem` (of type `object`) to your `SelectIndex` property (`int` property) in your view model (VM).  `ListBox` like many WPF controls have distinct `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedItem` properties for binding.

If you want to bind to an `int` property in order to get the index you should be binding the `ListBox`'s `SelectedIndex` property instead.

Change:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectIndex}" ...
```

...to:

```
<ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectIndex}" ...
```

Your VM remains as:

```
public int SelectIndex { get { return 1; } }
```

Though to be more useful and allow users to choose different items it should be:

```
public int SelectIndex { get; set; } // TODO: add support for INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Optionally you can add:

```
    <ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectIndex}" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ...
```

ViewModel:

```
    public int SelectIndex { get; set; } // TODO: add support for INotifyPropertyChanged

    // replace object with your type
    public object SelectedItem { get; set; } // TODO: add support for INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Comment: `replace object with your type` type of what?

Comment: @aepot whatever it is that your `ListBox` is showing.  `String`; `Person`; `Hamster` ...